# Difference between Python 3.3 and 3.4 `open` default encoding?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file with some non-ASCII characters.

```
$ file bi companies.txt
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

On my desktop with Python 3.4 I can `open` this file with no problems:

```
>>> open('companies.txt').read()
'...'
```

On a CI system with Python 3.3 I get this:

```
>>> open('companies.txt').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1223: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But if I explicitly specify `encoding='utf8'`, it works:

```
>>> open('companies.txt', encoding='utf8').read()
'...'
```

On both systems, `sys.getdefaultencoding` returns `'utf-8'`.

Any ideas what is causing the systems to behave differently? Why is the CI system trying to use ascii?

Comment: Always specify the encoding if you know it, rather than relying on the default encoding, which may change.

Comment: That may be good advice, but my question is particular to why the two systems are behaving differently despite the default encoding (as far as I can tell) being the same.

Comment: @AndrewMagee. What does `locale.getpreferredencoding()` return on each system?

Comment: Ah, that looks like it could be it. On the CI system, that returns `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'` so that would explain the difference. I wasn't aware of that being a thing. If you write that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding for text files is determined by [locale.getpreferredencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding), rather than [sys.getdefaultencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding).